# When I use WeakReference, cannot resolve symbol message on android

Tags: java, android, arraylist, weak-references

My app camera preview record app. 
I use `ArrayList`, during record camera preview.

`ArrayList` declared on global variable

`private ArrayList<OutputInputPair> pairs = new ArrayList<OutputInput>();`

and when I record stop button click, execute `stop()` method

```
@Override
public void stop() {
   pairs.clear();
   pairs = null;
   stopped = true;
}
```

so, If I continue recording without click record stop button. 
occur a lot of memory leak.

[image]

so, I want use `WeakReference`
I try this

```
//private ArrayList<OutputInputPair> pairs = new ArrayList<OutputInputPair();
  private ArrayList<WeakReference<OutputInputPair>> pairs = new ArrayList<WeakReference<OutputInputPair>>();  //global variable

 @Override
 public void add(OutputInputPair pair) {
    //pairs.add(pair);
    pairs.add(new WeakReference<OutputInputPair>(pair));
 }

 @Override
 public void stop() {
    pairs.clear();
    pairs = null;
    stopped = true;
 }

 @Override
 public void process() {  //record method
    //for (OutputInputPair pair : pairs) {
    for (WeakReference<OutputInputPair> pair = pairs) {
        pair.output.fillCommandQueues(); //output is cannot resolve symbol message 
        pair.input.fillCommandQueues(); //input is cannot resolve symbol message
    }

    while (!stopped) { //when user click stop button, stopped = true.
        //for (OutputInputPair pair : pairs) {
         for (WeakReference<OutputInputPair> pair : pairs) {
             recording(pair); //start recording 
         }
     }
   }

public interface IOutputRaw  {   //IInputRaw class same code.
    void fillCommandQueues(); 
}
```

I think How to avoid memory rick, use `WeakReference` is right?

How to fix cannot resolve symbol message use weakreference?

thanks.

```
public class OutputInputPair {
    public IOutputRaw output;
    public IInputRaw input;

     public OutputInputPair(IOutputRaw output, IInputRaw input) {
         this.output = output;
         this.input = input;
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know much of `WeakReference`. But you should use the `get()` method to get the actual reference.

Use:

```
if(pair == null) continue;
OutputInputPair actualPair = pair.get();
if(actualPair == null) continue;
actualPair.output.fillCommandQueues();
actualPair.input.fillCommandQueues();
```

instead of:

```
pair.output.fillCommandQueues();
pair.input.fillCommandQueues();
```

Comment: `null` check before using it is required.

Comment: No, not the pair, `pair.get()` can return null if the weakly referenced object was cleared.

Comment: @Oleg oops, edited again, as I mentioned I don't know much about `WeakReference`. Nevermind.

Comment: @Oleg `pair == null` ? check ?

Comment: Glad I could help. :)

Comment: @NabinBhandari   I have a one question, I use WeakReference and Build.  but occur memory leak., even with weakReference, occur memory leak?